# The general linear group over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $F$ be a finite field with $q$ elements. Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that, $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}(F^n)$.

I tried to relate a map with a matrix just like is done in linear algebra, but i have no idea how to build it since in vector spaces you have a basis. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Just pick a basis for the vector space $F^n$, the same way you do for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The hypothesis that $F$ is finite is entirely irrelevant.